# Azure HDI Spark import sqlContext.implicits._ error

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I;ve got problems with importing data from Azure Blob storage csv file to my Spark by Jupyter notebook. I'm trying to realize one of tutorials about ML and Spark. When I fill Jupyter notebook like this:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val flightDelayTextLines = sc.textFile("wasb://sparkcontainer@[my account].blob.core.windows.net/sparkcontainer/Scored_FlightsAndWeather.csv")

case class AirportFlightDelays(OriginAirportCode:String,OriginLatLong:String,Month:Integer,Day:Integer,Hour:Integer,Carrier:String,DelayPredicted:Integer,DelayProbability:Double)

val flightDelayRowsWithoutHeader = flightDelayTextLines.map(s => s.split(",")).filter(line => line(0) != "OriginAirportCode")

val resultDataFrame = flightDelayRowsWithoutHeader.map(
    s => AirportFlightDelays(
        s(0), //Airport code
        s(13) + "," + s(14), //Lat,Long
        s(1).toInt, //Month
        s(2).toInt, //Day
        s(3).toInt, //Hour
        s(5), //Carrier
        s(11).toInt, //DelayPredicted
        s(12).toDouble //DelayProbability
        )
).toDF()

resultDataFrame.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("FlightDelays")
```

I receive error like this:

```
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
<console>:23: error: not found: value sqlContext
       import sqlContext.implicits._
              ^
```

I used shortes paths as well like (`"wasb:///sparkcontainer/Scored_FlightsAndWeather.csv"`) this same error.
Any ideas?
BR,
Marek

Comment: Try import spark.implicits._

Answer (score 0):

When I see your code snippet, I don't see the sqlContext is created, refer the following code and get the sqlContext created and then start using it.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

[image]